# Submitting a form triggers an ajax call which posts to the action page on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a login form with a username and password. 
I make a post to a web service with the user and pass as parameters and I get back an ID for that user.

What I am trying to achieve is that on form submit, the ajax call is made which in turn populates the ID field (which I need) and then submits the form using `$('#form1').post();`.

To prevent default behavior, I have a `return false;` at the beginning of the `.submit()` event.

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {         
        $('#sajax-loader').show();        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{user:"' + $("#user").val() + '",pass:"' + $("#pass").val() + '"}',
            url: "URL.asmx/validate",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#id').val(data.d);                
                $('#sajax-loader').hide();                                             
                $('#form1').post();
                $('#login-notification').show();                                
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $('#login-notification').html("An Error Occured " + err);
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```

Obviously this is the wrong approach since I am not getting any response when submitting.

Can anybody guide me in the right direction? Give some advice on how to tweak this submit function I have here, or maybe an entirely different more practical approach?

Comment: Are you seeing a request go out, in fiddler or your browsers session inspector?

Comment: @imparator I'm wondering why you are having this `$('#form1').post();`? and have you looked at the console? Was there any error?

Comment: changed it to ~document.getElementById("form1").submit()~ and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginning `return false` will stop the execution of `submit()` function at that point from where you `return` and rest of the code is not executing. So, place your `return false` at the end.

In other way, using **[.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault)** will stop default form submission behavior.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) { 

        // instead of return false
        // use e.preventDefault()           

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#sajax-loader').show();        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{user:"' + $("#user").val() + '",pass:"' + $("#pass").val() + '"}',
            url: "URL.asmx/validate",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#id').val(data.d);                
                $('#sajax-loader').hide();                                             
                $('#form1').post();
                $('#login-notification').show();                                
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $('#login-notification').html("An Error Occured " + err);
            }
        });
    });
```

#### And one thing

Instead of

`data: '{user:"' + $("#user").val() + '",pass:"' + $("#pass").val() + '"}',`

you can use:

`data: {user: $("#user").val() ,pass: $("#pass").val() },`

Comment: The issue isn't that he was returning false, the issue is that he used return false at the beginning of his statement, if he would have moved it to the end of his code it would have worked as expected....

Comment: @thecodeparadox: From the jquery documentation "we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler." returning false does the same exact thing.

Comment: #ohgodwhy: I moved return false to the end and it still does not post to the desired page ... just wondering is `$('#form1').post();` to initiate a post?

Comment: #thecodeparadox: I still can't manage to get this working ... ~$('#form1').post();~ does not seem to post at all